# ReferenceError: function is not defined. In Jasmine unitest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, istanbul

I have a function need to test.

```
         var getPrepaidFieldInfo = function (field, root) {
            if (field === 'PatientDOB') {
                return {
                    fieldName: root.localizedStrings.patientDobLabel,
                    fieldValue: $filter('date')(new Date(root.principal.patientDob), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
                }
            }
            if (field === 'PatientLastName') {
                return {
                    fieldName: root.localizedStrings.patientLastNameLabel,
                    fieldValue: root.principal.lastName
                }
            }
            if (field === 'ZipCode') {
                return {
                    fieldName: root.localizedStrings.postalCodeLabel,
                    fieldValue: root.principal.zipCode
                }
            }
            if (field === 'Client') {
                return {
                    fieldName: root.localizedStrings.clientIdLabel,
                    fieldValue: root.principal.clientId
                }
            }
        };
```

And i write unitest for its.

```
it('getPrepaidFieldInfo should work properly', function(){
        expect(getPrepaidFieldInfo).toBeDefined();
        var field, actual;

        field === 'PatientDOB';
        spyOn(window.getPrepaidFieldInfo).and.CallThrough();
        actual = getPrepaidFieldInfo(field,$rootScope);
        expect(actual.fieldName).toEqual($rootScope.localizedStrings.patientDobLabel);

    });
```

But when i run it, it's shown error: ReferenceError: *getPrepaidFieldInfo is not defined*

How to check my function and solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

A reason could be using `var`, which would make your function only be defined in the scope you created it in. For example:

```
var foo = function() {
    var bar = function() { 
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

If I tried to call `bar()` outside `foo()` it would be undefined. But removing the `var` in `var bar` makes it global and defined anywhere. So change this:

```
var getPrepaidFieldInfo = function (field, root) {
```

to:

```
getPrepaidFieldInfo = function (field, root) {
```

Comment: Because I use 'use strict' mode. That must use var to write new function. Remove var it make more error :(

Comment: @PhamMinhTan Is that function being defined in a scope, you can use `var` but don't place it in any closures. That or don't use strict mode.